# Arrow functions in class throw error with webpack-encore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, webpack-encore

### Configuration

I'm using [webpack-encore](/questions/tagged/webpack-encore) with my [symfony](/questions/tagged/symfony) project to compile my [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) project. Up till now, I've used the basic `webpack.config.js` setup that should work out of the box with react [when enabling it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/reactjs.html):

```
// webpack.config.js
// ...

Encore
    // ...
    .enableReactPreset()
;
```

### What I've tried:

I went ahead and added babel configurations (that I don't think are needed) in hope that it would solve the problem, but it didn't:

```
.configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {
        // add additional presets
        babelConfig.presets.push('es2017');
    })
```

### Code example:

Here is an example of what should work, but it doesn't compile and throws the following error:

> Syntax Error: Unexpected token

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

//This works
const someExteriorHandler = () => {};

export default class Example extends Component {
   //error bad syntax, points specifically at the equal sign.
   someHandler = () => {

   }
   render(){return(<h1>This is a test</h1>)}
}
```

### Question

How do I get the babel compiler in [webpack-encore](/questions/tagged/webpack-encore) to compile Arrow functions in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was [solved](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/193).

> Having assignment of arrow functions in a class is not part of ES6. It
>   is part of a draft proposal for an upcoming ES version. Babel is able
>   to transpile it, but you will need to enable this transformation in
>   the babelrc file. The default babel config shipped in Encore when you
>   don't configure babel does not enable the transpilation of
>   experimental features.

### Install experimental features

```
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
```

### Configure webpack.config.js

```
.configureBabel(function(babelConfig) {

    //This is needed.

    babelConfig.plugins = ["transform-object-rest-spread","transform-class-properties"]
})
```

It should compile now, with all JSX features as well.